# How to choose the grid node that falls in Germany from gridded estimated climate data in R?

Tags: raster, r, grids-graticules, climate

I am newbie to deal with climate data, so let me go straight with my question. I downloaded data from [climate data](http://climate.geog.udel.edu/~climate/) which asked me to register first before accessing their dataset, and those data are `gridded estimated` for the global. In their website [climate data](http://climate.geog.udel.edu/~climate/), they told about `SPATIAL INTERPOLATION` where Monthly averages of station air temperature (T) were interpolated to a `0.5 degree` by `0.5 degree` latitude/longitude grid, where the grid nodes were centered on the `0.25 degree`. The gridded fields were estimated from monthly weather-station averages using a combination of spatial interpolation methods.

However, for those gridded estimated data, I intend to find a way to choose the grid nodes that fall into Germany, but I have a difficulty to do this in R. Is that possible to make this happen in R easily? How can I get this done?

**reproducible data**

So Now I loaded the dataset that I want to process in R. Here is how they look:

```
> dim(stations)
[1] 3002790      16
> class(stations)
[1] "data.frame"
> colnames(stations)
 [1] "long" "lat"  "Jan"  "Feb"  "Mar"  "Apr"  "May"  "Jun"  "Jul"  "Aug"  "Sep"  "Oct" 
[13] "Nov"  "Dec"  "year" "ID"  
> str(stations)
'data.frame':   3002790 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ long: num  -180 -180 -180 -180 -180 ...
 $ lat : num  71.2 68.8 68.2 67.8 67.2 ...
 $ Jan : num  -24.7 -27 -27.8 -26.8 -29.1 -25.4 -21.5 -20.2 -20 27.4 ...
 $ Feb : num  -24 -28.2 -28.5 -26.6 -28.4 -23.8 -18.9 -17.9 -18.7 28.3 ...
 $ Mar : num  -23.2 -27.2 -27.5 -25.7 -27.5 -22.9 -17.2 -17.1 -17.4 27.9 ...
 $ Apr : num  -18.3 -21.6 -22 -20.5 -22.3 -18.2 -14 -13.2 -14.1 27.2 ...
 $ May : num  -8.4 -9 -9.5 -8 -9.7 -6.1 -2.3 -2.2 -2.4 25.7 ...
 $ Jun : num  0.2 0.6 0.4 2.7 2.2 3.8 3.4 4.3 4.3 24.9 ...
 $ Jul : num  1.5 2.8 3 6 6.2 8.6 9.2 10.1 10.5 24.7 ...
 $ Aug : num  0.6 1.9 1.8 4 3.3 6 7.2 8.9 9.5 24.2 ...
 $ Sep : num  -2 -0.2 -0.8 0.5 -1.3 1.1 2.2 3.8 4.2 25.5 ...
 $ Oct : num  -9.6 -11.9 -12.7 -12.2 -15.4 -11.5 -7.1 -6 -6.4 26.3 ...
 $ Nov : num  -18.6 -22.7 -23.6 -23.2 -26.4 -22.3 -17.5 -17.8 -19.5 26.2 ...
 $ Dec : num  -22.4 -25.1 -26.8 -27.3 -31.1 -27.2 -22.6 -21.4 -21.7 26.8 ...
 $ year: num  1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 ...
 $ ID  : chr  "-179.75_71.25" "-179.75_68.75" "-179.75_68.25" "-179.75_67.75" ...
```

**Reproducible example**:

Here is the minimal reproducible example (just head of input datasets whre I picked up random geographic coordinates, so you could imagine the dataset hold geographic coordinates by global scale):

```
myDF <- data.frame(long=c(-179.75, -179.75, -179.75 ,-179.75 ,-179.75 ,-179.75 ,-179.75 ,-179.75 ,-179.75,-179.75),
                 lat=c( 71.25 , 68.75,  68.25,  67.75 , 67.25 , 66.75 , 66.25 , 65.75 , 65.25 ,-16.75),
                 Jan=c(-24.7, -27.0 ,-27.8, -26.8, -29.1, -25.4, -21.5 ,-20.2, -20.0 , 27.4),
                 Feb=c(-24.0 ,-28.2 ,-28.5 ,-26.6 ,-28.4, -23.8, -18.9, -17.9, -18.7 , 28.3),
                 March=c(-23.2 ,-27.2, -27.5 ,-25.7 ,-27.5, -22.9 ,-17.2 ,-17.1 ,-17.4 , 27.9),
                 Aprl=c(-18.3, -21.6 ,-22.0, -20.5 ,-22.3 ,-18.2, -14.0, -13.2 ,-14.1,  27.2),
                 May=c( -8.4 ,-9.0, -9.5, -8.0, -9.7, -6.1, -2.3, -2.2 ,-2.4, 25.7),
                 Jun=c(0.2,  0.6 , 0.4  ,2.7  ,2.2  ,3.8  ,3.4  ,4.3  ,4.3 ,24.9),
                 Jul=c(1.5 , 2.8 , 3.0 , 6.0 , 6.2 , 8.6 , 9.2 ,10.1 ,10.5, 24.7),
                 Aug=c(0.6 , 1.9  ,1.8  ,4.0  ,3.3  ,6.0  ,7.2  ,8.9  ,9.5 ,24.2),
                 Sept=c(-2.0 ,-0.2 ,-0.8 , 0.5 ,-1.3 , 1.1 , 2.2 , 3.8 , 4.2, 25.5),
                 Oct=c(-9.6 ,-11.9 ,-12.7 ,-12.2, -15.4, -11.5,  -7.1 , -6.0 , -6.4 , 26.3),
                 Nov=c(-18.6, -22.7, -23.6 ,-23.2 ,-26.4, -22.3, -17.5 ,-17.8 ,-19.5,  26.2),
                 Dec=c(-22.4 ,-25.1 ,-26.8, -27.3, -31.1 ,-27.2 ,-22.6 ,-21.4, -21.7 , 26.8),
                 Year=c(1980 ,1980 ,1981, 1981 ,1981 ,1982 ,1982 ,1982 ,1983 ,1983))
```

this is how gridded estimated climate data look like, Now I need to find a way to choose the grid nodes that fall into Germany. How can I make this happen easily in R?

**Update**:

you can access the `readMe` files about dataset that I am using it right now, please take a look [Here is the description of datasets](http://jmp.sh/3f6fgn2).

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277523/pulling-out-geographic-coordinates-of-all-german-weather-station-that-come-from/277528#277528 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277750/retrieving-all-coordinates-of-gridded-temperature-data-with-its-metadata-that-fa

Comment: Suspicious duplicate is suspicious. Is this homework?

Comment: @Spacedman no, I just started to do some case study by using this dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outline:

Get a Germany boundary polygon data set in lat-long coordinates - try `getData` from the `raster` package using the `GADM` data source. This can give you an `sp` class object.

```
  library(sp)
  library(raster)
  germany = getData(name="GADM",country="DE", level=0)
```

Convert your stations data frame into a spatial data frame using `sp` or `sf` package functions. I'll make some dummy data on a 1 degree grid:

```
stations = expand.grid(x=-180:180, y=-70:70)
stations$temp = runif(50901)
projection(stations)="+init=epsg:4326" # code for lat-long
plot(germany)
plot(stations, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

We can plot Germany and the station points. The points extend over the whole globe, this is only showing the region near Germany.

Now you can do a spatial overlay or "crop" of the station data with the Germany polygon data, leaving you with just the German station data.

```
projection(germany)=projection(stations) # everything is lat-long
inGermany = !is.na(over(stations, as(germany,"SpatialPolygons")))
plot(germany)
plot(stations[inGermany,],add=TRUE)
```

which produces:

[image]

Details of each of those operations can be found in various spatial data tutorials, and you would do well to read some.